# What is the incoming email address used on google-app-engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, email

I'm reading this article : http://code.google.com/intl/zh-CN/appengine/docs/python/mail/receivingmail.html

I'd like to know, is this the right article to read to deal with mail from others sent to me ?

My Gmail is zjm1126@gmail.com, so when someone sends email to zjm1126@gmail.com, can I do something automatically with the incoming mail?

**Update:**

The article say:

> Your app can receive email at addresses of the following form:
>
> string@appid.appspotmail.com

Where do I set this?

Answer (score 1):

> is article used to deal with mail from others send to me ?

Yes

> and my gmail is zjm1126@gmail.com , so someone send email to zjm1126@gmail.com,i can do something automatically use incoming mail ,yes ?

No (unless you configure GMail to forward it to the address the article tells you to use)

> where to set this ???

Nowhere. You are given your appid when you sign up.

Comment: so which is the address that some send to me  ??

Comment: They send to your appspotmail.com address.  Your gmail account has nothing at all to do with your appliciation, except that you can use the same account to login to your application as an admin.